# Can we create Joomla custom template with HTML

Tags: html, joomla

I'm new to Joomla.
I'm having a small doubt coming to creating Joomla templates. In the file structure provided by joomla I can see only index.php file. My doubt is can we create a Joomla template using HTML also. so that in the file structure it reads index.html.

Thanks in Advance and Merry Christmas.

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer. Are none of these helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It is important here to distinguish between "can" and "should" here. I believe you "can" make a template in an html file without losing all of the Joomla functionality because Joomla places modules using tags like `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />` which it will parse. I'm not positive, but fairly certain that the template does require a php to bootstrap it, but you could just have the php file include the html you want to use. The major drawback is that you will be losing all of the php helper methods that Joomla makes available for you, like `JURI::base()` for dealing with paths for your scripts/css, etc.

You definitely should take advantage of Joomla's capabilities with php, so use the php file. If you want to include some html files into that document, that's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. The `index.php` file you are referring to is the **root** index file, while each template has its own `index.php` file inside their folder inside templates folder. For example `templates/beez3/index.php` Joomla includes the `index.php` file of the chosen **template** during it's execution cycle. Failing to find such a file it will fall back to a preinstalled template throwing an error: *The template for this display is not available.* Also the frontend requests start by loading the **root** `index.php` file first and then proceed to other calls and `<jdoc:include type="component" />` won't load anything as it won't have any framework loaded or any joomla functionality at all. Finally no extension will work since they all require the `_JEXEC` constant to be defined as it's being defined in the root `index.php` file:

```
/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be written in php and you can certainly keep your theme that you created within the template folder, as for keeping .html you can always use htaccess to serve whichever extension you want.