# Joomla and the default index.php added to the URL

Tags: joomla

OK, I'm mainly curious on this issue...

Why do Joomla sites (maybe others as well, I just use Joomla) have the index.php added to the URLs of the web site.

I know how to remove it, using .htaccess, so that's not the issue, I'm mainly just curious as to why a site would want http://www.xxxx.org/index.php/contact-us/ as a URL?

Shouldn't it ALWAYS be http://www.xxxx.org/contact-us/, isn't that the way search engines want it?

Am I missing the point of having the index.php affixed the to URL? What is it's purpose?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Because they can't use .htaccess for some reson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that joomla uses the index.php in it's links is that the **root** `index.php` file is the main entry point for every application that runs on the site. All functions specific for showing content and manage the appearance get called inside this file. If you take a look at any of the joomla extension and core files you'll see a line at the beginning `defined(_JEXEC) or die('restricted access')` this constant is set at the `index.php` file and that is done to prevent direct access to those scripts from outside the joomla environment. For example if you were to restrict content using the joomla ACL passing all the requests from the root `index.php` file ensures that the user will have the appropriate privileges to access that page. That is also the reason of the **separate** `index.php` file inside templates. See this answer for more: [why not use html templates in joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769144/can-we-create-joomla-custom-template-with-html/20774897#20774897).

Comment: Right, totally makes sense. Thanks for the information. Would a site with a URL such as http://www.xxxx.org/index.php/contact-us/ be considered "bad" by SEO standards? Should we always remove the index.php (via .htaccess) from the URL? Is there a reason to keep the index.php in the URL?

Comment: I'm not a SEO specialist but I don't think it's bad practice having the index.php in the url. Furthermore the same joomla page can be accessed via `example.com/index.php/contact-us` and `example.com/contact-us`. IMHO you'd be better off using .htaccess to have not only SEO friendlier urls but also more easy for users to remember them if they need to.